# Ejecutar Eclipse 3.7.2 en Linux Mint 19 usando Java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, linux-mint, java-7

Tengo que realizar un proyecto bajo un plugin que requiere **Eclipse 3.7.2**, pero éste dejó de ser compatible cuando salió Java 8.

Actualmente tengo Linux Mint 19 y la última version de OpenJDK. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo funcionar?

Con una botella de los JDK de la version 7 creo, funciona ¿cierto?

Comment: ¿Te sirve oracle java 7?

Comment: Hola Bernardo. ¿Te valdría con instalar el JDK de Oracle Java 7 en vez del de OpenJDK?

Comment: Si, java 7 es lo mismo, hola Óscar

Comment: Hola de nuevo Bernardo. Llevo ya casi una hora intentando redactar la respuesta, pero la página de descarga de Oracle está caída :( en cuanto vuelva a responder sigo con la redacción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde hace unos años Oracle dejó de dar soporte y actualizaciones públicas a Oracle Java 7 y ahora sólo se puede hacer mediante entrada con usuario y contraseña a la web de Oracle, por lo que muchos PPA que ofrecían Java 7 ya no pueden descargar e instalar automáticamente Oracle Java.

Para instalar Oracle Java 7 en una distribución de Linux basada en Debian como Linux Mint debes navegar hasta la siguiente página para descargar el JDK:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html

Acepta el acuerdo de licencia y pulsa en el enlace `jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz` para que te envíe a la página de **Inicio de sesión en cuenta de Oracle** en la que tendrás que registrarte gratuitamente (o iniciar sesión con una cuenta que tengas) y descargar el archivo.

Partimos suponiendo que tienes instalado OpenJDK JDK 8:

```
# update-alternatives --display java
java - modo automático
 la mejor versión del enlace es /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java.
 el enlace apunta actualmente a /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
 el enlace java es /usr/bin/java
# update-alternatives --display javac
javac - modo automático
 la mejor versión del enlace es /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac.
 el enlace apunta actualmente a /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
 el enlace javac es /usr/bin/javac
# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.18.04.1-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)
```

Una vez descargado el archivo deberás descomprimirlo como root tecleando la siguiente instrucción:

```
tar zxvf jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm/
mv /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64
```

Ahora agregamos esta nueva versión a las alternativas del sistema operativo incrementando en 1 la prioridad que tiene OpenJDK por defecto:

```
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64/bin/java 1082
update-alternatives: utilizando /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64/bin/java para proveer /usr/bin/java (java) en modo automático
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64/bin/javac 1082
update-alternatives: utilizando /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64/bin/javac para proveer /usr/bin/javac (javac) en modo automático
```

Ahora ya podemos comprobar que estamos usando la nueva versión instalada:

```
# java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

Cuando quieras cambiar de versión deberás teclear:

```
# update-alternatives --config javac
Existen 2 opciones para la alternativa javac (que provee /usr/bin/javac).

  Selección   Ruta                                         Prioridad  Estado
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64/bin/javac    1082      modo automático
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64/bin/javac    1082      modo manual
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1081      modo manual

Pulse <Intro> para mantener el valor por omisión [*] o pulse un número de selección:
```

Si quieres mantener la versión de java de tu sistema de manera independiente a la usada por eclipse puedes hacer uso de este [parámetro de configuración de `eclipse.ini`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Linux_Example):

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64/bin/java
```

Basta con agregarlo en el archivo `eclipse.ini` justo antes de la línea que contiene el parámetro `-vmargs`:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
```

Cuando cargues Eclipse la próxima vez usará esa jvm para iniciar el programa:

```
$ ps -ef | grep java
... /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64/bin/java -Xms40m -Xmx384m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar <ruta>/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash -launcher <ruta>/eclipse/eclipse -name Eclipse --launcher.library <ruta>/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505/eclipse_1407.so -startup <ruta>/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar --launcher.overrideVmargs -exitdata e78023 -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64/bin/java -vmargs -Xms40m -Xmx384m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar <ruta>/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
```

Comment: Se puede colocar Java únicamente para un programa? Cuando esté inicia ingresar un comando? Para realizar que este ejecute con Java 7?

Comment: Claro. Puedes usar la ruta completa a Java así: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64/bin/java argumento1 argumento2 ...` en vez de simplemente `java argumento1 argumento2 ...`.

Comment: Java eclipse? Puede ser??  O no sirve?

Comment: Mira el script que carga eclipse y en él habrá algún momento en el que haga uso de `java` para cargar la aplicación.

Comment: He agregado información de cómo modificar el archivo de configuración de Eclipse para usar una jvm específica para Eclipse.

Comment: Gracias Óscar en serio, muy atento de tu parte!! Tengo que trabajar con Arduino y este ide funciona muy bien y mejor que el Arduino IDE

Comment: Tuve que utilizar la versión 1.5 de java, y asi si funcionó

Comment: ¿No te cargaba ni eclipse sin el plugin? ¿O lo intentaste abrir de una copia de seguridad que tenía el plugin instalado y activo? Quizá fuera por eso, porque redacté la respuesta conforme lo iba probando yo todo en mi propio equipo.

Comment: instalacion limpia, de cero! y funciono con el 1.5

Comment: Tendrías que haber instalado `openjdk-jdk-8` para tener instaladas las dependencias necesarias. Puedes probar si quieres, ya que tienes ambas versiones descargadas e instaladas.